# Adding dropdowns to each row in a column of a dataview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-3.5, dataview

I have a dataview with the following columns:

```
<Columns>  
    <asp:BoundField DataField="report_type" HeaderText="Report Type" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="report_type"/>  
    <asp:BoundField DataField="progress" HeaderText="Progress" SortExpression="progress"/>  
</Columns>
```

This works fine, it displays records from the database.

How do I replace the progress column and make it contain a dropdown for each row?  Where the dropdown contains `complete` and `incomplete`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Template column  in order to customize your render

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="..">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
     </asp:DropDownList>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use dropdownlist in edit mode, then:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="..">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <%# Eval("progress") %>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProgress" runat="server" DataTextField="progress" />
   </EditItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```